# error message trying to install homals package in R

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to install the Homals package - library(homals), but keep getting this error message:

```
library(homals)
```

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details: call:
>   dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) error: unable to load shared
>   object
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so,
>   6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
>   Reason: image not found Error: package or namespace load failed for
>   ‘homals’

I have a couple of my colleagues to run the same code, the same thing happens. I have re-install R studio to the newest version.

```
install.packages("rgl")
install.packages("homals") 
library(homals)
```

Any solutions for this? thank you.

Comment: Are you running R/Rstudio as an Admin user? If not, try that out and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: just double checked, I am running it as the Admin user.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully install on both Windows and Mac. I believe the root cause here is that you have R version 3.3 installed when you require at least v3.5.3 as per below:

```
library(homals)
Warning message:
package ‘homals’ was built under R version 3.5.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working now I've updated to v3.6